# how to do this simple merge in R?

Tags: r, merge

I want to merge two datasets in R.

```
> dt_1
  co_code co_stkdate bse_closing_price bse_returns
1   21042 1990-01-01             47.50      1.0440
2   21042 1990-01-02             48.75      1.0263
3   21042 1990-01-03             42.50      0.8718
4   22765 1990-01-01             37.00      1.0000
5   22765 1990-01-02             37.00      1.0000
6   22765 1990-01-03             37.00      1.0000


> dt_2
  co_code co_stkdate bse_market_cap  bse_pe
1   21042 1990-01-01       338.8650 10.7236
2   21042 1990-01-02       347.7825 11.0058
3   21042 1990-01-03       303.1950  9.5948
4   21042 1990-01-04       303.1950  9.5948
5   22765 1990-01-01       206.7147  6.2263
6   22765 1990-01-02       206.7147  6.2263
7   22765 1990-01-03       206.7147  6.2263
8   22765 1990-01-09       202.5246  6.1001
```

The final desired output is:

```
> dt_3
    co_code co_stkdate bse_closing_price bse_returns bse_market_cap  bse_pe
1     21042 1990-01-01             47.50      1.0440       338.8650 10.7236
2     21042 1990-01-02             48.75      1.0263       347.7825 11.0058
3     21042 1990-01-03             42.50      0.8718       303.1950  9.5948
4     21042 1990-01-04                NA          NA       303.1950  9.5948
5     22765 1990-01-01             37.00      1.0000       206.7147  6.2263
6     22765 1990-01-02             37.00      1.0000       206.7147  6.2263
7     22765 1990-01-03             37.00      1.0000       206.7147  6.2263
8     22765 1990-01-09                NA          NA       202.5246  6.1001
```

I tried merge but it is giving me a lot of rows (24) which is not desired.

```
> merge(x = dt_1, y = dt_2, by = "co_code")
   co_code co_stkdate.x bse_closing_price bse_returns co_stkdate.y bse_market_cap  bse_pe
1    21042   1990-01-01             47.50      1.0440   1990-01-01       338.8650 10.7236
2    21042   1990-01-01             47.50      1.0440   1990-01-02       347.7825 11.0058
3    21042   1990-01-01             47.50      1.0440   1990-01-03       303.1950  9.5948
4    21042   1990-01-01             47.50      1.0440   1990-01-04       303.1950  9.5948
5    21042   1990-01-02             48.75      1.0263   1990-01-01       338.8650 10.7236
6    21042   1990-01-02             48.75      1.0263   1990-01-02       347.7825 11.0058
7    21042   1990-01-02             48.75      1.0263   1990-01-03       303.1950  9.5948
8    21042   1990-01-02             48.75      1.0263   1990-01-04       303.1950  9.5948
9    21042   1990-01-03             42.50      0.8718   1990-01-01       338.8650 10.7236
10   21042   1990-01-03             42.50      0.8718   1990-01-02       347.7825 11.0058
11   21042   1990-01-03             42.50      0.8718   1990-01-03       303.1950  9.5948
12   21042   1990-01-03             42.50      0.8718   1990-01-04       303.1950  9.5948
13   22765   1990-01-01             37.00      1.0000   1990-01-01       206.7147  6.2263
14   22765   1990-01-01             37.00      1.0000   1990-01-02       206.7147  6.2263
15   22765   1990-01-01             37.00      1.0000   1990-01-03       206.7147  6.2263
16   22765   1990-01-01             37.00      1.0000   1990-01-09       202.5246  6.1001
17   22765   1990-01-02             37.00      1.0000   1990-01-01       206.7147  6.2263
18   22765   1990-01-02             37.00      1.0000   1990-01-02       206.7147  6.2263
19   22765   1990-01-02             37.00      1.0000   1990-01-03       206.7147  6.2263
20   22765   1990-01-02             37.00      1.0000   1990-01-09       202.5246  6.1001
21   22765   1990-01-03             37.00      1.0000   1990-01-01       206.7147  6.2263
22   22765   1990-01-03             37.00      1.0000   1990-01-02       206.7147  6.2263
23   22765   1990-01-03             37.00      1.0000   1990-01-03       206.7147  6.2263
24   22765   1990-01-03             37.00      1.0000   1990-01-09       202.5246  6.1001
```

I am new to R and merging. I try reading some stack overflow posts on left join, outer join etc but all of them gives me the same 24 rows. [How to join (merge) data frames (inner, outer, left, right)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1299871/how-to-join-merge-data-frames-inner-outer-left-right)

Comment: What you have is a many-to-many join. Each value of `co_code` joins to every instance of `co_code` in the other dataset. 4x3 = 12 rows of output for each `co_code`. You need to add a `time` column against each row within each `co_code` group, and add `time` to the `by=` variables.

Comment: @thelatemail Pls have a look at the question again, I edited some fields. I need to merge based on a unique combination of co_code and date. Adding a time variable will help if I somehow put the same time value in each dataset corresponding to the same combination of co_code and date.

Comment: If you have the date, it's just a one-to-one merge - `merge(x = dt_1, y = dt_2, by = c("co_code","co_stkdate"), all=TRUE)`

Comment: @thelatemail It seems to work. I knew I was missing something very basic. Let me test this. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

You can try the `dplyr` library to merge the two data frames.

Depending on whether you want all rows, just the ones in `dt_1` and the ones in `dt_2` that match `dt_1`, or the ones that are present in both frames, you might use -- respectively -- a `full_join`, a `left_join`/`right_join`, or an `inner_join`.

```
dt_3 <- full_join(dt_1, dt_2)
```

Since the columns in common have the same name, you don't need to specify a `by` condition.

You can check the syntax [here](http://stat545.com/bit001_dplyr-cheatsheet.html) as well.